# Angular: How to disable the event in directive?

Tags: angular, events, directive

I search the issue for several hours. but no answer.

How to disable the existing click event when a user is not logged in.

I have so many buttons to do change, so I do not want to change the old click event function.

I just want to add a appLimitedDirective for the buttons.

Any of the three positions will works.

```
component.html

<button
  (click)="onClickEvent()"
  appLimitedDirective>
  Click
</button>

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLimitedDirective]'
})
export class LimitedDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // 1. if the user did not logged in, disable the click event of the button.
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    // 2. if the user did not logged in, disable the click event of the button.
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    // 3. if the user did not logged in, disable the click event of the button.

    if (!this.loggedIn) {
      // all the functions do not work. the existing click function still can be executed.
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('you are not logged in, please do login. then will show a popup window for login...')
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

added an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ob2q2r

**I want to just disable the existing click event. and ensure the button is clickable.**

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ob2q2r

Answer (score 1):

I found a method to resolve this issue.

```
@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event']) onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (!this.loggedIn) {
      const currentItem = event.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
      currentItem.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      alert('you are not logged in, please do login. then will show a popup window for login...');

      // method 1. settimeout to reset the button.
      setTimeout(() => {
        currentItem.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');
      }, 200);

      // method 2. show a popup dialog, when user close the dialog, reset the button.
    }
  }
```

example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eq53tv)

Comment: works great for when an attribute binding on the element overrides a directive that suppose to disable the button. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `disabled` host binding, pointing to the user logged in:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'button[appLimitedDirective]'
})
export class LimitedDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @HostBinding('disabled')
  isNotLoggedIn: boolean = true;

  // ...
}
```

It's unclear where you would get the logged in information from, but I'm sure you'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to disable all these buttons (better ux). You can do this by:

        `<button
            [disabled]="userNotLoggedIn"
            ...
        </button>`

It is the same effort as setting a directive. The variable 'userNotLoggedIn' must be set in the corresponding components.